# Execute file on remote system

Tags: windows

Users have been experiencing extreme logon times (10 minutes) intermittently. The company I work for currently does not use sites so users can be authenticated or have GPs applied from DCs around the U.S. With a bit of research I was able to develop a powershell script that captures useful information--script found below. Anyways, I copied the script onto various machines. Now I just need to be able to run the script as needed remotely. I created a shortcut for the PS script that by-passes the Execution Policy setting (currently default). I've tried executing the shortcut with psexec.exe and powershell neither works correctly.

**PSExec**

```
psexec $computer -u $user $file
```

> Error: PsExec could not start $file on $computer: The system cannot find the file specified.

Meanwhile, I can double-click the shortcut locally and it works without issue.

**Powershell**

```
PS [Local Computer]>Enter-PSSession -ComputerName $computer -Credential $user
PS [Remote Computer]>cmd /c $file
```

> Error: Starting a command on the remote server failed with the following error message: The I/O operations has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request...

**Script**

```
$USER = $env:username.ToUpper()
$COMPUTER = $env:computername.ToUpper()
$Current_Time = Get-Date
$PCname = ''
$addedtime = 0
$LogonServer = $env:logonserver
$GPApplied = cmd /c gpresult /r | find "Last time Group Policy was applied"
$GPServer = cmd /c gpresult /r | find "Group Policy was applied from"
$LogonInfo = "C:\Temp\LogonDurations.txt"
$GPApplied = $GPApplied.TrimStart() 
$GPServer = $GPServer.TrimStart() 

#Get event time of last successful logon
$filterXML = @'
<QueryList>
  <Query Id="0" Path="System">
    <Select Path="System">*[System[Provider[@Name='Microsoft-Windows-Winlogon'] and (Level=4 or Level=0) and (EventID=7001)]]</Select>
  </Query>
</QueryList>
'@
$LogonDateTime=(Get-WinEvent -ComputerName $PCname -MaxEvents 1 -FilterXml $filterXML -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).timecreated

#Get Win License validated after logon (about same time as explorer loads)
$filterXML = @'
<QueryList>
  <Query Id="0" Path="Application">
    <Select Path="Application">*[System[Provider[@Name='Microsoft-Windows-Winlogon'] and (Level=4 or Level=0) and (EventID=4101)]]</Select>
  </Query>
</QueryList>
'@
$DesktopTime=(Get-WinEvent -ComputerName $PCname -MaxEvents 1 -FilterXml $filterXML).timecreated

#Get Logon Duration
$LogonDuration = "{0:N1}" -f ((($DesktopTime - $LogonDateTime).TotalSeconds + $addedtime)/60)

$output = @"
------------------------------------------------------------------ 
$COMPUTER $Current_Time 
------------------------------------------------------------------ 
Logon Server:  $logonserver 
$GPApplied
$GPServer

Successful Logon @  $LogonDateTime  
Desktop Appeared @  $DesktopTime 
Duration of Logon =  $LogonDuration minutes  

"@

$output | out-file -FilePath $logoninfo -Append
```

Comment: `Users have been experiencing extreme logon times (10 minutes) intermittently. The company I work for currently does not use sites so users can be authenticated or have GPs applied from DCs around the U.S.` - If that's the root of the problem why aren't you fixing that?

Comment: I'm local admin not network admin. I don't have rights to fix that problem. I was told supply network admins with info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I use and it works like a charm:

> PSEXEC \\MachineName -u UserName -p Password -w WorkingFolder powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command FullPathToScript.ps1

Given the reformatted quesiton (Thank you HBruijn) when you're calling PSEXEC it is attempting to run $file from some unknown working folder.  Use the -w switch on your PSEXEC command line to set it to the folder where your ps1 exists on the remote machine.  Assuming permissions are otherwise copacetic then you should have a successful execution.

The reason that I actually use PSEXEC to call PowerShell itself is to ensure that the ExecutionPolicy is set.  This is much the same reason that I set the working folder and then fully qualify the path to the ps1.  I try to be as explicit as possible to help troubleshoot should things go pear shaped.

Comment: $GPApplied = cmd /c gpresult /r | find "Last time Group Policy was applied"
$GPServer = cmd /c gpresult /r | find "Group Policy was applied from"
Doesn't appear execute (both null) as a result I get an error on $GPApplied = $GPApplied.TrimStart() and $GPServer = $GPServer.TrimStart. Script works without issue when ran locally

Comment: Script located in C:\Temp on remote machine. I ran the following command:
psexec $computer -u $user -w C:\Temp powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command C:\Temp\$file.ps1.

The script partially executes but $GPServer=GPServer.TrimStart and $GPApplied=$GPApplied.TrimStart results in error. I still get logon duration but I don't get GP Server

Comment: try:  $GPR = cmd /c gpresult /r  $GPApplied = $GPR | find "Last time Group Policy was applied" $GPServer = $GPR | find "Group Policy was applied from" .  It'll run faster, and you'll get to see the raw result of the GPRESULT command as well.  I'd hazard a guess that GPRESULT isn't outputting something correctly.

Comment: $GPR=INFO: The user does not have RSOP data
??

Comment: Not seen that before.  It may mean that there are no GPOs applied to that particular user on that particular machine.  Try GPUPDATE /FORCE and see what you get.  May require a reboot though, so beware.

Comment: I believe I have a solution http://woshub.com/diagnose-group-policies-issues-with-gpresult/